# How can I verify that my query is causing no locks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking, transaction-isolation

Suppose that I'm having a bad day and my confidence just isn't with me. Suppose also that I've written a query with `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted`. After it runs for a few minutes, I get scared that I've messed something up and could be causing locks. By opening another query window, how can I verify that my query is definitely not causing locks?

Assume that I have full admin-level access everywhere. The classic procedures of Adam Mechanic's and Brent Ozar are already installed.

Comment: the fact you want to set set transaction isolation level read uncommitted" could mean you have an XY problem. What's your actual problem ? Locks are held as part of normal, healthy operations. Are you concerned with blocking? if so, sp_whoisactive displays any blocking chains....

Comment: Even `READ UNCOMMITED`/`NOLOCK` causes locks.

Comment: You check dm_tran_locks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 or maybe watch karate kid to psyche yourself up

Comment: This is probably an XY Problem, but locks can be seen in `sys.dm_tran_locks`. But `READ UNCOMMITED` is unlikely to be the right answer for whatever you are doing.

Comment: One problem is that your query might not hold any locks *now* but It can do that in the future making your quest for non-locking harder to solve.

Comment: Why do you think `read uncommitted` *could be causing locks*? Of course it *takes* locks, as the name suggests it simply means it does not honour some locks held by *other* transactions, so your query results could be incorrect.

Comment: Beware of READ UNCOMMITTED or NOLOCK tag in tables. In certain circumstances the NOLOCK is ignored and a real lock is placed on some resource on the table. As an exemple this is systematically the case when using a DECRYPT... function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the locks held by session 67 (for example) you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE request_session_id = 67
```

And to see whether session 67 is causing blocking to other sessions you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
WHERE blocking_session_id = 67 AND session_id <> blocking_session_id
```

Comment: all true, but I suspect that's not the OP's actual problem

Comment: I imagine the second query will be more useful. As generally the "worry" for running an adhoc query would be around blocking

Comment: Still the real answer is probably to use `SNAPSHOT`

Comment: It's "an answer" - but this may not be enabled and so not something you would enable untested on a production database to run an adhoc query.

Comment: The first query reveals my ignorance. I was surprised to see it return anything at all for my query that had `with (nolock)` everywhere. I must think more on this.